# how to add timer to jquery loading div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried using the below code to have a div display as a loading screen. But it dissapears as soon as the page loads.. I want it to stay for 5 seconds while things in the background load, and then dissapear. How do I do this? I tried adding setTimeout but it didn't do anything

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
    setTimeout(document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none", 5000)
});
```

```
#loading {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: $black;
}

.loading_logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```
<div id="loading">
    <img class="loading_logo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/lib/images/header-logo.svg">
</div>
```

Comment: Start by reading the setTimeout() documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` should be

```
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none", 5000); // ES6 syntax
```

Or

```
setTimeout(function() { 
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none"
}, 5000); // ES5 syntax
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `setTimeout` with a callback function like so

```js
setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}, 5000)
```

The function will run after 5000 miliseconds.

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tg1r4dpq/

Also, you can run the code below.

```js
function loadingImg() {
    var loading_logo = document.getElementById("loading_logo");
    setTimeout(function() {
    loading_logo.style.visibility = "hidden"
  }, 5000);
}

loadingImg();
```

```css
#loading {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: $black;
}

.loading_logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="loading">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" id="loading_logo" class="loading_logo" />
</div>
```